# Подсчет суммы по ключам?

Tags: php, массивы

Массив:

```
$arr = array(
    'Ford'=> array(
        array('id'=>1,'name'=>'Alex','cost'=>12.50),
        array('id'=>2,'name'=>'Max','cost'=>55.11),
        array('id'=>3,'name'=>'Igor','cost'=>18.00)
    ),
    'BMW'=> array(
        array('id'=>1,'name'=>'Dmitry','cost'=>16.30),
        array('id'=>2,'name'=>'Vlad','cost'=>15.55),
        array('id'=>3,'name'=>'Stas','cost'=>8.00)
    ),
);
```

Как по каждой машине высчитать сумму и добавить ключ с ее значением к каждой машине? Ну т.е. сложить все `cost`, напр.

```
['BMW']['Price'] = (16.30 + 15.55 + 8.00) = 39,85
```

[[@xEdelweiss](/users/7017/xedelweiss)](/users/7017/xedelweiss), вот что вышло:

```
   foreach ($arr as $key=>$val) {
        $sum = 0;
        foreach ($val as $m) {
            $sum+=$m['cost'];
        }
        $arr[$key]['Price'] = $sum;
    }
```

Можно сказать `Решение найдено`.

**По заявкам**

```
foreach ($arr as $key=>$val) {
    $arr[$key]['Price'] = 0;
    foreach ($val as $m)
        $arr[$key]['Price'] += $m['cost'];
}
```

Comment: @Maris, пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Ну вроде правильно, если вы с синтаксисом не напутали. (Дисклеймер: я не разбираюсь в PHP.) А что не так выходит с вашим кодом?

Comment: С нашим все в порядке, как вы и просили добавил 2-й вариант.

Answer (score 1):

Красивенько:

```
$sum = array();

foreach ($arr as $carType => $car) {
    $sum[$carType] = array_sum(array_map(function ($row) {
        return $row['cost'];
    }, $car));
}

var_dump($sum);
```

`array(2) { ["Ford"]=> float(85.61) ["BMW"]=> float(39.85) }`